# Deltaspikes @WindowScoped working with TomEE?

Tags: jsf-2, el, apache-tomee, deltaspike

I'm struggeling how to get Deltaspikes @WindowScoped working with TomEE (did try 1.5.2, 1.5.3-SNAPSHOT and 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT)

Its a very minimal war, with deltaspike 0.4 core+jsf dependencies.

Now, i did create a HelloWorldBean like this:

```
@Named("HW")
@WindowScoped
public class HelloWorldBean implements PassivationCapable,Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("Bean did get constructed");
    }
....
}
```

There's an empty beans.xml, empty faces-config.xml and a very minimal web.xml.

on a very simple page i have.

```
<h:form>
           <h:inputText value="#{HW.name}"></h:inputText>
       <h:commandButton value="Welcome Me" actionListener="#{HW.printIt}"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
```

The page works fine, a windowId is added to the request and when i refresh the page i see that the bean is not instanciated (i.e. test() gets only called once).
But as soon i press the commandButton i get an ContextNotActiveException exception:

```
org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareELException: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'name' on type de.glauche.beans.HelloWorldBean$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:104)
    at javax.faces.component._DeltaStateHelper.eval(_DeltaStateHelper.java:249)
    at javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:67)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getValue(UIInput.java:151)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:618)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:274)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:213)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1427)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1427)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._processValidatorsDefault(UIViewRoot.java:1456)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.access$500(UIViewRoot.java:74)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot$ProcessValidatorPhaseProcessor.process(UIViewRoot.java:1563)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._process(UIViewRoot.java:1412)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:812)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsExecutor.execute(ProcessValidationsExecutor.java:38)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:170)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at org.apache.deltaspike.jsf.impl.listener.request.DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.execute(DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper.java:75)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'name' on type de.glauche.beans.HelloWorldBean$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:68)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:58)
    at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:179)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.webbeans.el22.WrappedValueExpression.getValue(WrappedValueExpression.java:70)
    at org.apache.myfaces.view.facelets.el.ContextAwareTagValueExpression.getValue(ContextAwareTagValueExpression.java:96)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: javax.enterprise.context.ContextNotActiveException: WebBeans context with scope type annotation @WindowScoped does not exist within current thread
    at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:299)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.getContextualInstance(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.webbeans.intercept.NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.get(NormalScopedBeanInterceptorHandler.java:70)
    at de.glauche.beans.HelloWorldBean$$OwbNormalScopeProxy0.getName(de/glauche/beans/HelloWorldBean.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:64)
    ... 41 more
```

Am i missing something obvious? Or is it a bug in DeltaSpike? (or TomEE?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Exception indicates that the windowId is not set in the WindowContext. Did you add the proper DeltaSpike tag into your fragment?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
  xmlns:ds="http://deltaspike.apache.org/jsf">

<h:head></h:head>

<h:body>
<ds:windowId/>
...
```

The ds:windowId part is important. 
You can debug into DeltaSpikeLifecycleWrapper#execute to see if the windowId gets detected properly.

Comment: Aaaah .. was missing that one, its different from CODI i think. Added the tag and everything works perfectly. Thanks!